# Unable to create new Application in Itunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I am not able to create a new application from my itunes connect account. Is there some limit on the number of application a user can create. I have only created 2 so far.

[image]

Comment: Do you still unable to create a new application?

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no limit on number of apps created. That could be caused by a non-signed agreement(s).

**Agreements, Tax, and Banking**

> The following contracts are expired: iOS iAd Agreement. This could be
>   affecting the availability of your apps. To request and complete your
>   updated contracts, go to the Agreements, Tax, and Banking module.

**Review the iOS Paid Applications Agreement**

> The iOS Paid Applications Agreement has been updated. To create new
>   apps and upload binaries to the App Store, the user with the Legal
>   role must review and accept this agreement in the Agreements, Tax, and
>   Banking module.

Go one step back to home page and check if you have any notifications pending.