# iTunes connect -cant add a new app?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

We used to add new apps by going to `"apps"` than tap the `"+"` button, and a menu should be open says- `add a new iOS app`.

Now, when we hit the "+" button , we only see `create bundle` option .

All contracts are ok, why could it happen ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to create new Application in Itunes Connect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27345347/unable-to-create-new-application-in-itunes-connect)

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27345347/unable-to-create-new-application-in-itunes-connect

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Developer account homepage and check if any notification pending such as sign Agreement(s). Because this type of issue caused by non-signed Agreement(s).

Answer (score 0):

Use safari instead of chrome or any other browser.